# Malloc Error Caused by Realloc

Tags: c, macos, malloc, xcode5, realloc

I've been scratching my head over this for hours. I'm running Mac OS X 10.8, with XCode 5. I've been getting the following error:

```
malloc: *** error for object 0x1006487b8: incorrect checksum for freed object - object was            
probably modified after being freed.
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
```

Unfortunately, `object 0x1006487b8` is freed at this point, and my debugger has no recollection of what was there.

The problem is, the error never occurs in the same place. I can only assume that a bit of memory isn't freed properly, and then the computer tries to use it for some other purpose and winds up confused.

My code is using SDL 2, and as far as I can tell, the only `free` -like function call occurs in the following form with a `realloc`:

```
static LGC_Gate* LGC_CreateEmptyGate(){
    if (!gates) {
        gates = malloc(sizeof(LGC_Gate));
        if (!gates)
            return NULL;
    }
    else{
        LGC_Gate* tmpgates = realloc(gates, sizeof(LGC_Gate) * (numgates + 1));
        if (tmpgates)
            gates = tmpgates;
        else
            return NULL;
    }
    numgates++;
    gates[numgates - 1].id = numgates - 1;
    return &(gates[numgates - 1]);
}
```

`gates` is a static, file-scope pointer to an array of gates and is declared as such at the top of the file:

`static LGC_Gate* gates = NULL;`
`numgates` is initialized to zero at the beginning of the file, and represents the number of gates currently in use. `gates` should always be of size `numgates * sizeof(LGC_Gate)`.

My plan was to hold all gates created by the user in a single array, so that it was easy to tally them and get each at a moment's notice. The `LGC_CreateEmptyGate` function is used like this, for example:

```
LGC_Gate* LGC_InitActGate(LGC_Action act, uint8_t innum, uint8_t outnum){
    LGC_Gate* product = LGC_CreateEmptyGate();
    if (!product)
        return NULL;

    product->rule.type = LGC_FUNCTION;
    product->rule.act = act;

    product->input.used = innum;
    product->input.val = 0;
    product->output.used = outnum;
    product->output.val = 0;

    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        product->inputfrom[i].active = 0;
    }

    return product;

}
```

Have I done something horribly wrong?

### Update

I have done some debugging with the following code:

```
printf("%d\n", sizeof(LGC_Gate));
LGC_Gate* TestGates[5];
//Go through the gates, initialize each of them, record the value of their ptr,
//and if any are LESS than sizeof(LGC_Gate) apart, report an error.
int gcount;
for (gcount = 0; gcount < 5; gcount++) {
    TestGates[gcount] = LGC_InitActGate(LGC_NOR, 2, 1);
    printf("%p\n", TestGates[gcount]);
    if (gcount < 4) {
        if (TestGates[gcount] + sizeof(LGC_Gate) > TestGates[gcount + 1]) {
            printf("Error!");
            //TestGates[gcount + 1]->id = 4;  If this line were uncommented, 
            //                                BAD_ACCESS ensues.          
        }
    }
}
```

To my complete surprise, this actually outputs an error, and indeed crashes on some of the pointers. CORRECTION: The erroring pointer always seems to be the third one. Note that `LGC_InitActGate` calls `LGC_InitEmptyGate` once, and simply copies data for the rest of its duration. What is going on?

### Update 2

Well, I believe I've discovered the error now. Every time realloc is called, the entire block of memory may or may not relocate, which renders the array of 5 pointers I had useless and pointing to old, freed memory. This makes total sense, but it's one heckuva bug. I should've noticed before. I'm not sure how to fix this, but thanks for the help I got.

Comment: nothing like reading through a long question and the coming to end and discovered it has already been solved. /sigh

Comment: @claptrap Put a notice at the top.

Comment: Strongly encourage you to familiarize yourself with the "memcheck" option of "valgrind".

Comment: You could post an answer to your own question and then even accpet this answer. This keeps you from having to things like this "SOLVED" comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every time `realloc` is called from `main`, the memory block may or may not relocate, which leaves the array `TestGates` have elements that point to invalid memory.

Answer (score 1):

What this error is telling you is that the system is about to try and allocate some memory, but when it went to it's free pool, the next available block appears to have been corrupted.

```
void* p = malloc(100);
free(p);
strcpy(p, "How do you like these apples, malloc?";
p = malloc(100); // <-- crash may happen here, depending on how the free list works.
```

It is usually the case that the location of the crash is merely the detection and not the cause.

One way you can sometimes track down a crash like this is look at the data at the address (and get lucky and have something recognizable like a string or well known values).

Otherwise, it's time to break out valgrind.

Answer (score 0):

The code looks fine to me, although it could be simplified since you don't actually need to special-case the starting condition. [Note 1]

Are you certain that you're not holding on to a pointer to a "gate" somewhere in the code? You have to be really careful with auto-reallocating vectors, particularly global ones which might be modified in a function:

```
LGC_Gate* product = LGC_CreateEmptyGate();
some_innocuous_looking_function();  // Oops, this function calls CreateEmptyGate
product->output.val = some_value;
```

---

Note 1: From the Posix [realloc specification](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/realloc.html):

> If ptr is a null pointer, realloc() shall be equivalent to malloc() for the specified size.

Comment: Thanks for the info and the help, but unfortunately this doesn't fix the problem. There's no other place where any dynamic memory is handled...

Comment: @BrainSteel: The error says "object was probably modified after being freed". That's (only tangentially) about allocation. Mostly it's about *modifying* an object using the wrong pointer (as in, one which has just been left to dangle). The example I provided is a common way this happens, but there are many other ones. You have to look at every place where you have a pointer to a gate and check to make sure that the pointer does not live through a call to CreateEmptyGate

Comment: I have new information now, and I'm now very, very confused. Updating the question with code.